# dropping various columns using iloc

Tags: pandas, indexing

Say I have a dataframe `df1` with a bunch of columns:

```
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close', 'log_return',
   'close_open', 'Daily_Change', '30_Avg_Vol', '20_Avg_Vol', '15_Avg_Vol',
   '9_Avg_Vol', 'changed', 'p_changed', '5days', '7days',
   '7days_10daysAvg', '5_7days_Avg', '-2_before', '-1_before', '0_before',
   '1_before', '2_before', '3_before', '4_before', '5_before', '6_before',
   'Bullish'],
  dtype='object')
```

I want to create a new dataframe that keeps some of the columns and drops others. I want to keep columns 0-13, 13-19, 19-28  (using offset notation)

I tried variations of these

```
x2 =df.iloc[:-5, [0:13,13:19, 19:28 ]]     # meant to edit 13:19 in this line
x2 =df.iloc[:-5, [[0:13],[13:19], [19:28 ]]
```

but no luck. I get a `syntaxerror`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [**`np.r_`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
df.iloc[:-5, np.r_[0:13, 13:19, 19:28]]
```