# Third parameter of np.r_? (numpy)

Tags: numpy, concatenation

I'm looking over the docs and I still can't figure out how the third parameter operates.

```
 np.r_['0,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

output:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
```

2)

```
np.r_['1,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

The first parameter is the axis, second is the number of dimensions and third according to the docs means " which axis should contain the start of the arrays which are less than the specified number of dimensions"

Here are the docs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

Thank you.

Comment: I've answered a lot of `np.concatenate` related questions, and almost never have used that string parameter of `r_`.  Nor seen it used by others.  No harm in learning to use it, but don't worry if it remains a mystery.

Comment: I've never used it as well, but in another thread I made with a different problem, a user had it as part of the solution. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102869/dropping-various-columns-using-iloc

Comment: While it can be used for general purpose concatenation, it is most useful when constructing indexes like that.  All the code in `index_tricks.py` (I think that's its file name) is instructive.

Comment: Where can I find index_tricks.py? Is it the examples given in the docs?

Comment: `..../numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` is the full path .  In an ipython session I can do `np.lib.index_tricks??` to read the file.

Comment: This is particularly tricky to learn by experimentation, because until 1.13, [getting it wrong broke all future uses of `np.r_`!](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8815)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a simple example can clear things up:

```
b=np.arange(3)
np.r_['0,2,0', b, b]
# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2],
#        [0],
#        [1],
#        [2]])
np.r_['0,2,1', b, b]
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [0, 1, 2]])
```

We are concatenating `b` a 1d array with itself. The second number specifies that it should be made 2d before it gets stacked on itself as specified by the first number. Now there are two ways to make a shape (3,) array 2d: either make it (3, 1) (first example) or make it (1, 3) (second example). The third number specifies where the first original dimension (i.e. 3) goes in the 2d array.

Comment: So a 0 is equivalent to using `b[:,None]`, 1 to using `b[None,:]`.

Comment: Thanks. `Now there are two ways to make a shape (3,) array 2d: either make it (3, 1) (first example) or make it (1, 3) (second example)`    This statement really helped clear up things. I'm glad you included it in your explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Compare np.r_['0,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]] with np.r_['0,2,1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]. You don't get a simple dimensions switch from (2,3) to (3,2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the existing answer is right. From my testing it seems that setting the third integer at 1 is the default and doesn't make a change. But setting it at 0 results in NumPy going into every row in your array, and turning all its elements into individual rows. So if your array has a row [1,2,3] inside of it, it becomes [1],[2],[3].

```
np.r_['0,2,1', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6]])

np.r_['0,2,0', [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
#array([[1],
#       [2],
#       [3],
#       [4],
#       [5],
#       [6]])
```

It also seems that Numpy only splits up the elements of the *outermost* row into individual rows:

```
np.r_['0,2,1', [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]]
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html
Negative integers specify where in the new shape tuple the last dimension of upgraded arrays should be placed, so the default is ‘-1’.

what does this sentence mean?

```
np.r_['0,2,-5', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ] # ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
np.r_['0,2,-6', [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ] # array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]])
```